# ASP.NET and PHP on the same webpage

Tags: php, asp.net

I'm wondering if there would be any problems using PHP on an ASP file? I plan to develop a website where I'll be inserting PHP code to load some info from a database but i'll be using ASP for the layout of the site.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you're wondering, why not try it out yourself? Setup IIS with both Asp and PHP FastCGI and try it out

Comment: Hi Nakadale, it seems to me you've yet to read "[How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" Go ahead and take a look, and then edit your question to reflect what you've learned there.

Comment: Why would you do this instead of learning Web Forms or Razor?

Answer (score 3):

This is actually quite possible... if completely boneheaded, in this author's opinion, but it's a fun challenge. Here's how you'd do it:

If you'd like to use PHP to process the file initially, and then use ASP.NET, I would begin by using a `VirtualPathProvider` which uses a `HttpClient` (if .NET 4.5+) or `HttpWebRequest` to make the request to the resource that will be processed by PHP, the `VirtualPathProvider` is a means of making ASP.NET use a virtual filesystem, it's how you can store `.aspx` and `.ascx` files in a database, for example.

If you'd like ASP.NET to process the file initially and then use PHP, it's a bit more difficult, but still doable: you'd use ASP.NET as usual, but implement an `IHttpModule` which intercepts the result from ASP.NET and provides it as `stdin` to the PHP CGI executable, and then returns the result.

Implementing both proposals is an exercise left to the reader.

Comment: thank you Dai, i'll check them out and check whether which uses the least resources and latency.

Comment: @Nakadale both approaches are an exercise in futility. There is no reason you can't use a single platform, either PHP or ASP.NET - they're both solid capable platforms which can perform both tasks (data collection + display and content layout) admirably.